# How can I find coefficients a, b, c given two points?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Suppose I have two points $A(x_A,y_A)$ and $B(x_B,y_B)$.

How can I find coefficients $a, b, c$ of the straight line general equation ?

$a x + b y + c = 0$

Comment: If $x_A\ne x_B$, use ${y-y_B}={\textstyle y_B-y_A\over \textstyle \strut x_B-x_A}(x-x_B)$. Write this in your desired form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is
$$(y_A-y_B)x-(x_A-x_B)y+x_Ay_B-x_By_A=0.$$

Comment: So $a=(yA−yB)$, $b=(xB−xA)$ and $c=xAyB−xByA$?

Comment: Yes. If you set $(x_A,y_A),(x_B,y_B)$ in the left hand side, you'll get $0$.

Comment: I have done something similar and find $c = -a x_A - b y_A$ is that possible? I mean, I just isolated $c$ in the equation later.

Comment: Since $ax_A+by_A=c$, of course it is possible. But since each of $a,b$ is what you wrote, it is equal to the $c$ I wrote.

Comment: I afraid of the sign. You wrote $ax_A+by_A=c$ but isn't $ax_A+by_A=\color{red}-c$? Which gives $\color{red}-ax_A\color{red}-by_A=c$

Comment: Oh, sorry. my mistake. you are right.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\neq 0$, divide the general equation by $a$ and then substitute $(x_A,y_A)$ and $(x_B,y_B)$ into the obtained equation. See if you get the solution. If there is no solution to the system, it means that $a = 0$. Again find $b$ and $c$ by substituting $(x_A,y_A)$ and $(x_B,y_B)$ into your equation. (The thing is that if you multiply your equation by a nonzero constant, you'll of course obtain equation of the same line...)